# Having Runtime error in C programing :(

Tags: c

My friend and I have written a C code, that we give a reverse sentence to it and it print a regular sentence for us. We must upload this code to a server and it check our code with some test cases and give us score. But in some test cases it says that our code has runtime error and we must make our code shorter. the other problem is when we use writing signs like `?` or `!` etc, our program doesn't work true.

Example input: `oD uoy tnaw ot eunitnoc?`

output (we want): `Do you want to continue?`

output it shows: `Do you want to ?continue`

Can you help us to make this code shorter and solve this problem?

Thank you.

Our code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
   char sentence[100];
   int ch, i, j, k;

   for (i = 0; (sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
   {
       ;
   }
   sentence[i] = '\0';

   for (j = 0; j <=i; j++)
   {
           if (sentence[j] == ' ' || sentence[j] == '\0')
           {
                   for (k = j-1; sentence[k] != ' ' && k >= 0; k--)
                   {
                       ch=sentence[k];
                       putchar(ch);
                   }
                   printf(" ");  
           }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding `&& i < sizeof(sentence)-1` in the stop-condition of the first `for` loop.

Comment: i am curious, is the  first `for` loop running for more than 1 character

Comment: thank you but how can i make the code shorter ?

Comment: I would rewrite the first loop as `for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++) if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n') break;` because part of your question is runtime errors.

Comment: @haris: If you don't press enter after the first character, then yes.

Comment: can you change it and give me the final code ?

Comment: I have used for (i=0; i<sizeof(sentence)-1; i++) if ((sentence[i] = getchar()) == '\n') break; Instead of the first loop and my problem with runtime error solved . but how can i solve the second problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you were being told your code was too long and not that the input was too long (which it was)? As for the `?` being misplaced, try using `isalpha()` or `isalnum()` instead of comparing with `' '`

Answer (score 1):

The code is treating "eunitnoc?" all as one word and hence printing out "?continue". You can make the loop shorter by not going all the way to the last character, which shouldn't be included in the last word.

As for making the length of the code shorter: Why not remove the line where you change the final '\n' to '\0' (and change the logic accordingly as well). That will shorten the code. Do you care about decreasing the number of lines? You could remove some whitespace.

Like this, for example, should do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int ch, i, j, k;
    for (i=0; (sentence[i]=getchar())!='\n';i++){;}
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (j==i)
        {
            putchar(sentence[j-1]);
        }
        else if (sentence[j]==' ' || j==i-1)
        {
            for (k=j-1;sentence[k]!=' ' && k>=0;k--)
            {
                ch=sentence[k];
                putchar(ch);
            }
            if(j!=i-1)printf(" ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my English is not well . Can you give me the final code that you mentioned to it ? thank you bro .